# Class:hover doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a little problem with Firefox, this is the html

```
<html>
<button name="five" data-type="select" class="ui_button ui_button_normal">
<span>Pasta</span>
<div class="ui_button ui_button_normal ui_select_list">
    <div class="ui_select_list_item" name="Pasta">Pasta</div>
    <div class="ui_select_list_item" name="Carne">Carne</div>
    <div class="ui_select_list_item" name="Verdura">Verdura</div>
    <div class="ui_select_list_item" name="Pesce">Pesce</div>
    <div class="ui_select_list_item" name="Dolce">Dolce</div>
    <div class="ui_select_list_item" name="Frutta">Frutta</div>
    <div class="ui_select_list_item" name="Caffè">Caffè</div>
</div>
</button>
</html>
```

and this is the CSS

```
.ui_select_list 
{
margin: 0px !important;
height: auto !important;
padding: 10px;
}
.ui_select_list_item 
{
border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.ui_select_list_item:hover 
{
border: 1px solid transparent;
background-color: rgba(0, 185, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #000000;
border-radius: 10px;
}
.ui_button 
{
background-color: rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.5);
border: 0 solid transparent;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
color: #FFFF00;
font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
height: 32px;
line-height: 30px;
margin: 5px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 160px;
}
.ui_button_normal 
{
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.ui_button_normal:hover 
{
background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/Mak73/3YkSe/

The problem is that, on Google Chrome  it works like expeted, when the mouse is over the div.ui_select_list_item the content of the div change with div.ui_select_list_item:hover.

On Firefox the :hover don't work, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you're wrapping a `<button>` around the divs .. close it after the `<span>` and the `:hover` state will work  ..

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3YkSe/2/

Comment: I voted it down, but took it back instantly. I however noticed you didn't remove the closing tag from the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try applying the following element options:

display: none; 
   display: inline;

I think this will do some better work in Firefox, on focus pop the
menu and display it inline, without block. This is just an idea I've 
got for you to try out. Reply back if it works or not! Thanks!